# Difference between multiprocessing.Pipe and multiprocessing.connection.Pipe

Tags: python, pipe, multiprocessing

I've found that python.org has official documentation for `multiprocessing.Pipe`, but my PyCharm IDE suggests me to import `multiprocessing.connection.Pipe`, which has no documentation. Built-in help system says as follows:

```
>>> from multiprocessing import Pipe as P1
>>> from multiprocessing.connection import Pipe as P2    
>>> help(P1)
Help on method Pipe in module multiprocessing.context:

Pipe(duplex=True) method of multiprocessing.context.DefaultContext instance
    Returns two connection object connected by a pipe

>>> help(P2)
Help on function Pipe in module multiprocessing.connection:

Pipe(duplex=True)
    Returns pair of connection objects at either end of a pipe
```

So what's the difference, where the docs and which one should I use?

Comment: why dont you look into the source code?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out it's actually the same thing. In file [multiprocessing/context.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/multiprocessing/context.py) I've found the following lines:

```
def Pipe(self, duplex=True):
    '''Returns two connection object connected by a pipe'''
    from .connection import Pipe
    return Pipe(duplex)
```